# re-execute FORM several times from other FORM c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem to re-execute  a  FORM several times...

1) First FORM 'FormGroupe':

[image]

- first  FORM to enter the number of repetitions in the textBox 'Nombre de Groupe'
- by clicking the 'Valier' button, the other appears FORM

2)Second FORM 'FormPRINCIPAL' :

[image]

I WANT to re-execute  this Second FORM  according to the number (eg, 5 times)

int compteur = int.Parse(textBoxtest.Text); (textBoxtest : this is the number of repetitions)

my code:

int ij=1;

Normal processing of my application.....

```
do
{
    FormPRINCIPAL   ff = new FormPRINCIPAL();
    ff.Show();

    ij++;
} while (ij <= compteur);
```

But always i have Error!

I get 5 times display 'FormPRINCIPA'  at the same time !! So crashed  my application!!

Thanks ,

Comment: In a `for` loop, use `ShowDialog()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this as Reza said

```
Form2 f;
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            f = new Form2();
            f.ShowDialog();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for replay

this time , i have one FORM display...then another FORMdisplay....indeterminate loop !!